# Determine which scatter points are within a filled area in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, graphics, position

I'm running an experiment to determine if geometric borders influence agents to coordinate in certain economic games.

I have made a graph of a unit square randomly partitioned into two parts using the following method:

In python (not super relevant)...

1. Create a self-avoiding random walk and store the lattice-points visited
2. Jitter the lattice points a bit
3. Format the jittered points as a highcharts series

with Highcharts (more relevant)...

4. Render the jittered points as type "areaspline"

I also add in some uniformly scattered points (appearing as circles, i.e. the players).

All of which yields a chart like this:

[image: Example]

Which is exactly what I want.

My question is, how can I identify which scatter points are in which partition? My intuition is that HighCharts must identify the set of points to fill in when I call areaspline and that I should be able find the intersection of that set and my set of scatter points. Supposing that is correct, I can't find a way to return the set of filled in points. If incorrect, then I'm really lost! Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo** (click and drag to create area): http://jsfiddle.net/vsbrwgso/

It uses **ray casting algorithm** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) to find the point within the path.

```
var pointInPolygon = function(point, vs) {
  // ray-casting algorithm based on
  // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

  var x = point[0],
    y = point[1];

  var inside = false;
  for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
    var xi = vs[i][0],
      yi = vs[i][1];
    var xj = vs[j][0],
      yj = vs[j][1];

    var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
    if (intersect) inside = !inside;
  }

  return inside;
};
```

You should adjust this example to your needs (remove interactivity, use areaspline/polygon series instead of user selection etc.)

Comment: OP here. Super cool and knowledgeable answer! I am on a different project today but I'm confident this example will guide me through. Funny story, I was about to reinvent the ray-casting algorithm (apparently known since 1962) which would have been a huge waste of time. Sometimes you just need to learn the jargon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better of using python to find which scatter points are in which partition. It should be possible to compare a scatter point with coordinate (x_scatter, y_scatter) to the line at the same x value. That is;

```
if x_scatter == x_line and y_scatter > y_line:
  scatter point is in white portion of graph
elif x_scatter == x_line and y_scatter < y_line:
  scatter point is in the gray portion of the graph.
```

I say this because as far as I know, there is no inherent way for highcharts to tell if a point is overlapping another series' point. Of course something can be done in javascript to do this calculation as well, but since you already know these variables in python it seems like unnecessary extra work.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that. The problem is python isn't really constructing lines. It's just making a collection of vertices. HighCharts is connecting the vertices to make the lines. It's also converting the lines to splines with something called a cubic bezel algorithm. So implementing the proposed approach means I would have to either write my own bezel algorithm or incorporate one into my code. This just seems like so much work when HighCharts is clearly coloring in one of the partitioned areas (implying it has already identified a partition).